# Where do I find the data which shows up on the Sitecore Storefront?

Tags: sitecore, storefront, commerce, sitecore-commerce-server

Where can I View/Configure the data related to shipping Charges that is visible on the Storefront at checkout ?
I want to change the default shipping cost values to my custom values. Please help me out with a way of doing it.
[image: Storefront Checkout Page]

Thanks

Comment: better to ask this on https://sitecore.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

The default shipping fee is stored in policy file - GlobalPhysicalFulfillmentPolicy